# Отслеживать открытие Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-on-click

Хочу отслеживать событие открытия Spinner. Попробовал повесить на него `View.OnClickListener`, не получается: вылетает с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
        at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:774)
```

Comment: Простите за глупость а зачем оно вм?)

Comment: @elik, убрать первый пункт "Выберете..."

Comment: Его и без того можно убрать )не пойму зачем вм слушатель

Comment: @elic, мне надо чтоб до открытия spinner 1й пункт был виден, а после - нет.

Comment: Советую обратить взор на Spinner от матеиал дизайна такм такая функция есть

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста. В appcompatspinner? Как функция называется?

Comment: классическая проблема XY. Когда задаете вопрос, спрашивайте о той проблеме, которую действительно нужно решить (скрыть пункт спиннера при раскрытии), а не о вашем [неправильном] способе решить проблему (как повесить слушатель на спиннер). Это даст вам правильное решение действительной проблемы.

Comment: Минус вам за полное изменение вопроса. Так нельзя делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо написать кастомный `Spinner`, типа:

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner {
   //blah-blah
}
```

и переопределить метод `public boolean performClick()` там ловить его состояние открыт/закрыт ну и т.д.